# How do I make a react component break out of its iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I am creating a react component that is hosted on one server, and will be embedded through an iframe on another regular HTML page. I want to have a button that brings up a full-screen modal on the HTML page, regardless of the size of the iframe. Is this possible?

Solutions I've tried:

- Using CSS `fixed` and `absolute` display attributes. This doesn't work, as it sees only the iframe as the screen. Even `100vh` and `100vw` values only fill the iframe.
- Giving the root of the HTML page an id, and using document query selectors and `appendChild` to create a new node directly on the HTML page. The error here is that `document.getElementById` can't find any elements outside the iframe.

The `document` variable seems to be confined to the iframe only, this might be because the React Component webserver is sending an entire HTML doc, with it's own DOCTYPE html and <html> tags. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Both the iFrame and the parent page need to come from the same server to do this.

The only way around this is to host JS on the parent page and use the pstMessage API to communicate between the two.

The iframe-resizer-react library might be helpful with this.